# Unable to restore database

Tags: sql-server, restore

I'm trying to write a program that will restore many databases, query them using LINQ and then write recieved data to my database.

The first problem I've encountered is that I can't restore any database programatically. 
The error says something like this:

> "File 'xxx' cannot be restored to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\xxx.mdf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file."

I've checked and that's indeed a problem. I haven't got this folder (\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS). How to resolve this?

My code for restoring:

```
private void RestoreDB(string destPath, string dbName, string fileName)
    {
        var myServer = new Server(@"LOCALHOST");

        var res = new Restore();
        res.Database = dbName;

        res.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
        res.Devices.AddDevice(destPath, DeviceType.File);
        res.PercentCompleteNotification = 10;
        res.ReplaceDatabase = true;

        try
        {
            res.SqlRestore(myServer);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{dbName} couldn't be restored");
            return;
        }
    }
```

The thing is, I've recently migrated from once PC to another. It worked before but I recall that I've had some problems with SQL before as well. I've read something about this error but I need explanation step by step how to deal with it.

Comment: Try a different destPath that exists on the machine. One that the SQL services log on users have access to.

Comment: Use Restore.RelocateFiles Property to set the new destination  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.restore.relocatefiles?view=sqlserver-2016#Microsoft_SqlServer_Management_Smo_Restore_RelocateFiles